# Create a table with unique and random name from my web application

Tags: mysql, database, yii

I am trying to create a temporary table in my database from my yii application. I want the tables to give a randomly generated name(preferably concatenated with 'user_'). I tried the below code. But does'nt work.

```
    $command = $connection->createCommand(
    'SET @tbName = MD5(RAND());
    CREATE TABLE @tbName LIKE master_table;
    INSERT @tbName SELECT * FROM master_table;'
    )->execute();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tbName = 'user_' . md5(rand());

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
    "
    CREATE TABLE `".$tbName."` LIKE `master_table`;
    INSERT INTO `".$tbName."` SELECT * FROM `master_table`
    "
)->execute();
```

Tested and working for me!

Comment: The SQL being executed was: CREATE TABLE `".$tbName."` LIKE

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly - or did you change any of the single or double quotes? It looks like $tbName isn't being parsed as a variable when you're using it.

Comment: Oops..missed the double quotes!